# String variable with input

Tags: java

Not really sure how to put the title so sorry if that's wrong.

I'm trying to get information from a configuration and put that into a message but I have to make a new string every time I do that because I'm very new to java and barely understand the language.

Basically what I want to do is have a global variable like config() but I am unsure of how to do that.

```
    String configOne;
    String configTwo;

    public Test(Test test) {
        this.configOne = test.getConfig().getString("messages.testOne");
        this.configTwo = test.getConfig().getString("messages.testTwo");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        System.out.println(configOne);
        System.out.println(configTwo);
```

But what I want to do is

```
    String config();

    public Test(Test test) {
        this.config = test.getConfig().getString(<input>);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        System.out.println(config("messages.testOne");
        System.out.println(config("messages.testTwo");
```

Also doing

```
System.out.println(test.getConfig().getString("messages.testOne"));
```

doesn't work and just errors.

Sorry for the question I'm sure its probably quite easy.

Comment: *"doesn't work and just errors."* An error message is a *message* telling you something about your code. What does it say?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full stack trace. The stack trace includes essential information about which method and which line of code caused the error.

Comment: Please update the question with the errors that you have got.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, you're not entering the input correctly.

It should probably be something like this:

```
String config= in.nextLine();

public void stringTest(String config) {
    this.config = config;
}
```

And then from there, you can just call upon config every time

```
System.out.println (config);
```

Edit: The reason you were getting that error was that your Strings didn't have any values. If you just wanted to initialize a string, just initialize it with "".

```
String str = "";
```